# Error: Unexpected properties found on Cognitive Search's Text.SplitSkill

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

When trying to define the skill Text.SplitSkill, I get an error if I try to use either the pageOverlapLength or the maximumPagesToTake properties:

Error:

"details": [
{
"code": "InvalidSkillset",
"message": "One or more skills are invalid. Details: Unexpected properties found on Skill. Parameters: skillset"
}

I tried to used, verbatim, the skill definition as indicated in this Microsoft document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-textsplit

Skill definition (copied from link above):

{

```
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",

"textSplitMode" : "pages", 

"maximumPageLength": 1000,

"pageOverlapLength": 100,

"maximumPagesToTake": 1,

"defaultLanguageCode": "en",
"inputs": [
    {
        "name": "text",
        "source": "/document/content"
    },
    {
        "name": "languageCode",
        "source": "/document/language"
    }
],

"outputs": [
    {
        "name": "textItems",
        "targetName": "mypages"
    }
]
```

}

I tried using this URL:

https://{{search-service-name}}.search.windows.net/skillsets/{{skillset-name}}?api-version={{api-version}}

with api-versions 2020-06-30-Preview and 2023-07-01-Preview.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`
"pageOverlapLength": 100,

"maximumPagesToTake": 1,`

take out these two parameters, and it should work.

```
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
```

"textSplitMode" : "pages",

"maximumPageLength": 1000,

"pageOverlapLength": 100,

"maximumPagesToTake": 1,

"defaultLanguageCode": "en",
"inputs": [
{
"name": "text",
"source": "/document/content"
},
{
"name": "languageCode",
"source": "/document/language"
}
],

"outputs": [
{
"name": "textItems",
"targetName": "mypages"
}
]

Answer (score 0):

apologies for any confusion. That is a piece of documentation that must be removed. We are coordinating removal accordingly. We will publish soon, when that property is available for public use.

Answer (score 0):

Even after removing below, after saving those properties are appearing back. Any suggestions

"pageOverlapLength": 100,

"maximumPagesToTake": 1,`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).